# Transparent Background

Tags: android, transparency, transparent

How can i make the background 50% transparent?
Let's say the background of an AbsoluteLayout so it's dark but you can still see through it?

Comment: AbsoluteLayout is deprecated.. you likely want a FrameLayout instead.

Comment: mmm i cannot use anything else, I need to be able to add items to the screen at runtime, and set their x,y,width, and height.
Is this possible with frame layouts?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could apply a transparent theme to the required activity. Create a new style in /res/values/style.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="Transparent">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Translucent</item>
<item name ="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:colorForeground">#fff</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

The value of transparent is

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

Now in AndroidManifest.xml declare the theme of the activity to the one you just created.

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" android:theme="@style/Transparent"></activity>
```

Comment: Same question but on a standard Android Button (the default grey ones), can you make it 50% transparent ? I was just wondering ...

Comment: Answering this:  if you want only 50% transparency, you would set the first 2 numbers to 50 instead of 00.  So it would be #50000000 - the first 2 numbers in a color define the transparency level.

Comment: @Booger , your statement about #50... resulting in 50% transparency is not correct. The color (and transparency) scale goes from 00 to FF in hexadecimal notation or from 0 to 255 in decimal. Thus, the correct html value for 50% transparency would be #7F000000.

Comment: This works.  My application was to disable touch but still allow a remote to press the underlying buttons of the app so I could not disable the buttons themselves.  This is a very cleaver solution     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text=""
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:clickable="true"/>