# Transparent LinearLayout on Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, transparent

I have the folowing layout:

[image]

I want to make transparent the **transparent_layout** but i can't do it.

Already tried settings the background programmatically with the color: Color.TRANSPARENT but it seems it doesnt work.

Im using Android 2.3.3 SDK with SherlockActionBar.

Is there any way to set that layout to transparent?

Comment: Post the layout.xml file for clarity

Comment: and also the code you are using the set the background color since you mentioned you're doing this programmatically. You have to use `setBackgroundColor` and not `setBackground` (just sayin' incase that's the issue).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114675/transparent-background

Comment: @CRUSADER, here you have the layout (http://pastebin.com/07rW2DWD).

Comment: @Ali im using setBackgroundColor, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: @Raghunandan i need to aply transparency to a layout, not a entire activity, please read well my post. I already tried that way. Thanks

Comment: @Alexandru you can apply the same to your layout. modify the same accordingly

Comment: @Raghunandan, i tried the example but it still dont work :(
I tried this project (http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1021) in my mobile and it works, the problem its not the sdk, there is something wrong in my ui..

Comment: Try [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8968905/2345913). I think its close to what you want to achieve

Comment: Don't forget to mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 45):

Depending upon the degree of opacity you like, set the background color like

```
        android:background="#00ffffff"
```

The first two digits are for opacity level, (aka alpha) that varies from 00 to ff (fully-transparent to fully-opaque), the remaining digits are for the desired background color. If you keep first 2 digits zero (00), then whatever color you choose for the remaining digits, doesn't matter.

Comment: 00 is  the transparency you want. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In XML change the main layout's (LinearLayout) background as `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` and also make sure that you are not giving the background to any of its child views.

Comment: you can give it a try [How to create Transparent Activity in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2700683/2310673)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Please keep helping others. Thanks